# Selenium WebDriver - Xpath (or anything) to locate cell next to cell in table?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have this table:
[image: table]

It's a ginormous table, so I'll just include here the relevant code.
As you can see, in the table I have lots of td with red x's:

```
<td>
<img id="imgPartStatus" title="Part Not Found/Part Unavailable" src="../../../App_Themes/Theme/Images/red-x.gif" alt="Part Not Found/Part Unavailable">
</td>
```

So what I'm trying to do is have some code (not part of the question) that goes through all of the td's in the table, and when it finds one like this (green check icon)...:

```
<td>
<img id="imgPartStatus" title="Part Available at Gateway" src="../../../App_Themes/Theme/Images/grn_chk.gif" alt="Part Available at Gateway">
</td>
```

...I want it to select the checkbox next to it (visible to the right of the x or the check icons). Luckily, the checkbox and the red/green icons are in the same tr, which should make things easier.

This is the code of the checkbox next to the green icon:

```
<td>
<input id="chkSelectPart" name="$chkSelectPart" onclick="chkNCJL(this,'True');" type="checkbox">
</td>
```

The question here is:

What's a good xpath to "JUMP" to the td next (to the right) of a td?
PS. It doesn't have to be an xpath. But since I'm going to click it after locating it, xpath should be good for that.
I'm still working towards understanding the relationships in xpath (preceding siblings, etc).

Thank you for checking out my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one go with an XPath expression:

```
//tr[starts-with(td/img[@id="imgPartStatus"]/@title, "Part Available")]/td/input[contains(@id, "chkSelectPart")]
```

Here we basically locate the `tr` where the `img` title starts with `Part Available`, then, in the located `tr` find the `input` with `id` containing "chkSelectPart" inside.

Comment: Can you help my a little bit by fixing that last part of /td/input[@id="chkSelectPart"] to contains? chkSelectPart is just part of the real IDs.

Comment: It's working that way, but I would also like to remove my dependency on locating the image by ID. I've tried using //tr[starts-with(td/img[contains(@id='imgPartStatus')]/@alt,'Part Available at Gateway')]/td/input[contains(@id,"chkSelectPart")] but it won't work. Little help by fixing it to contains, too? Please

Comment: Oh nevermind, contains is used with a comma, not equals. So this would be the correct expression:
/tr[starts-with(td/img[contains(@id,'imgPartStatus')]/@alt,'Part Available at Gateway')]/td/input[contains(@id,"chkSelectPart")]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with one of the following

```
//td/img[@alt='Part Available at Gateway']//following::input[@type='checkbox']


//td[img[@alt='Part Available at Gateway']]//following-sibling::td/input
```